# Angular Js 405 DELETE Method Not Alowed

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, http-delete, http-method

I have the following code in Angular

```
DepartmentController.prototype.delete = function (id) {
    this.departmentResource.delete(id);
};
```

The error is

```
DELETE http://localhost:64956//api/departments 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

My department factory is :

```
 var Company;
    (function (Company) {
        function departmentFactory($resource, servicePath) {
            return $resource(servicePath + "/api/departments/:serverAction/:id", null, Company.DepartmentResourceActionDescriptors.actions);
        }
        Company.departmentFactory = departmentFactory;
        departmentFactory.$inject = ['$resource', 'servicePath'];
    })(Company || (Company = {}));
```

I put a breakpoint after call delete method from controller and the id looks ok . Can anyone help me please?

Comment: There is a double slash in the request

Comment: Your calling /employees and you're showing code for /departments. Are you sure this is the resource that you're using?

Comment: That seems to be an issue with your endpoint, not Angular itself (do you have a route for it and/or CORS configured properly?). (Also notice the double slashes in the URL.)

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing serverAction, which is required the way you wrote your resource factory.

Use:

```
params {
    serverAction: { squash: true, value: null }
}
```

in your resource to make it optional.
And remove the slash of /api.

B.t.w. what is serverAction for anyway? You might want to remove that(?)